# Select all rows where rows in another joined table match condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql, querydsl

So I want to select all rows where a subset of rows in another table match the given values.
I have following tables:

```
Main Profile:
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
| id |  name  | subprofile_id | version |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
|  1 | Main 1 |             4 |       1 |
|  2 | Main 1 |             5 |       2 |
|  3 | Main 2 |           ... |       1 |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+

Sub Profile:
+---------------+----------+
| subprofile_id | block_id |
+---------------+----------+
|             4 |        6 |
|             4 |        7 |
|             5 |        8 |
|             5 |        9 |
+---------------+----------+

Block:
+----------+-------------+
| block_id | property_id |
+----------+-------------+
|        7 |          10 |
|        7 |          11 |
|        7 |          12 |
|        7 |          13 |
|        8 |          14 |
|        8 |          15 |
|        8 |          16 |
|        8 |          17 |
|      ... |         ... |
+----------+-------------+

Property:
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+
| id |        name        |          value           |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 10 | Description        | XY                       |
| 11 | Responsible person | Mr. Smith                |
| 12 | ...                | ...                      |
| 13 | ...                | ...                      |
| 14 | Description        | XY                       |
| 15 | Responsible person | Mrs. Brown               |
| 16 | ...                | ...                      |
| 17 | ...                | ...                      |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

The user can define multiple conditions on the property table. For example:

- Description = 'XY'
- Responsible person = 'Mr. Smith'

I need all 'Main Profiles' with the highest version which have ALL matching properties and can have more of course which do not match.
It should be doable in JPA because i would translate it into QueryDSL to build typesafe, dynamic queries with the users input.

I already searched trough all questions regarding similar problems but couldn't project the answer onto my problem.
Also, I've already tried to write a query which worked quite good but retrieved all rows with at least one matching condition. Therefore i need all properties in my set but it only fetched (fetch join, which is missing in my code examplte) the matching ones.

```
from MainProfile as mainProfile
  left join mainProfile.subProfile as subProfile
  left join subProfile.blocks as block
  left join block.properties as property
where mainProfile.version = (select max(mainProfile2.version)from MainProfile as mainProfile2 where mainProfile2.name = mainProfile.name) and ((property.name = 'Description' and property.value = 'XY') or (property.name = 'Responsible person' and property.value = 'Mr. Smith'))
```

Running my query i got two rows:

1. Main 1 with version 2
2. Main 2 with version 1

I would have expected to get only one row due to mismatch of 'responsible person' in 'Main 2'

---

### EDIT 1:

So I found a solution which works but could be improved:

```
select distinct mainProfile
from MainProfile as mainProfile 
  left join mainProfile.subProfile as subProfile
  left join subProfile.blocks as block
  left join block.properties as property
where mainProfile.version = (select max(mainProfile2.version)from MainProfile mainProfile2 where mainProfile2.name = mainProfile.name)
and ((property.name = 'Description' and property.content = 'XY') or (property.name = 'Responsible person' and property.content = 'Mr. Smith'))
group by mainProfile.id
having count (distinct property) = 2
```

It actually retrieves the right 'Main Profiles'. But the problem is, that only the two found properties are getting fetched. I need all properties though because of further processing.

Comment: I would use something like this in plain SQL: https://rextester.com/KVRHOC46305 but I don't know if that is usable in QueryDSL let alone JPA

Comment: You want to match all properties, so you should replace the 'or' in you query with 'and'. Then you can remove the 'having' clause.

Comment: I don't think you need a dynamic query, you can probably pass a list of properties as a parameter and do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934950/select-all-rows-where-rows-in-another-joined-table-match-condition

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your example. I'll try to implement that in jpql if it's even possible
 
JoostLambregts That won't work because there is no property which has two given names at the same time. You linked my own question. Can you correcnt the link please.